# THREE.js move Orthographic camera up and down without changing camera orientation

Tags: three.js

I am using Orthographic camera with OrbitControls and it works fine for zooming in and out (with mouse scrollwheel) and panning left and right (holding mouse right button down).

But I would also like to be able to "pan" the camera up & down (I believe the technical term is "boom" or "jib").

OrbitControls doesn't provide this motion.

What can I do to drive such a vertical motion from the mouse?

Answer (score 3):

You can set which mouse buttons perform which action [with `OrbitControls.mouseButtons`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.mouseButtons). It sounds like you already have rotating and dolly (AKA zoom in/out), but you still need to set the desired pan (up/down/left/right) button.

```js
controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
}
```

Don't forget to also set the [`.screenSpacePanning` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.screenSpacePanning) to either true or false, depending on what your desired behavior is. My guess is you want it set to `true`, but play with it to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Left/right panning was already working and it seems that OrbitControls does not provide up/down panning.